# Compare a computer simulation to an SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, computational-mathematics, stochastic-differential-equations, simulation

I am currently reading Anderson & Kurtz's [Stochastic Analysis of Biochemical Systems](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-16895-1). In this book, one studies chemical reaction networks and also how to simulate these with MATLAB. I know, that there is also a package in the [R Project](https://www.r-project.org) called [GillespieSSA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GillespieSSA) that can be used for those kind of simulations, too. So far, I was able to implement some of the algorithms. However, I am wondering, how I could compare my simulated graphs to an actual SDE. To be more precise: I have the assumption that one graph (or one species in terms of chemical reaction networks) should be following a specific SDE

$$dX_t=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t$$

How can I check, that my simulation is in fact 'solving' this SDE? Do I need to work with the expectation and variance of the simulation over time and compare it to some theoretical value? I have the feeling, that there must be a way to compare a computational value to a theoretical value, to verify, that my simulation is a possible candidate for a solution of this SDE, so to speak.

I'd be happy for any hint or help! Any book or paper recommendation are very welcome, too!

Comment: Construct a family of Brownian paths with a small step size, compute numerical solutions to them using multiples of that small step size. These can be directly compared. So you get a distribution of errors over the paths, for different step sizes and at different time points (that are common to all step sizes). // Or take test SDE with known solutions $X_t=f(t,W_t)$ to get exact errors. But in most SDE the solution will depend on the full history of the Brownian path, not only on the current value.